# Boruvka/Sollin's algorithm for MST

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, data-structures

Please help me regarding following problem-

Let us consider Boruvka/Sollin's algorithm . Note that Boruvka/Sollin algorithm
selects several edges for inclusion in T at each stage. It terminates when only
one tree at the end of a stage or no edges to be selected.

Algorithm 1: One Step of Boruvka/Sollin's
Algorithm
1: Find minimum cost edge incident toevery vertex.
2: Add to tree T. 3: Remove cycle if any.
4: Compress and clean graph (eliminate multiple edges).

(a) Suppose that we run k phases of
Algorithm 1, using the output G0 produced by one phase as the input G to the
next phase and accumulating edges in T. Argue that the overall running time of the
k phases is O(kE).

(b) Suppose that after running k phases
of Algorithm 1, as in part (5a), we run Prim's algorithm by calling MST-PRIM (G0;
c0; r), where G0, with weight attribute c0, is returned by the last phase and r
is any vertex in G0(V). Show how to pick k so that the overall running time is
O(E lg lg V ). Argue that your choice of k minimizes the overall asymptotic
running time.

(c) For what values of jEj (in terms of
jV j) does the above scheme asymptotically beat Prim's algorithm without
preprocessing?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted. You may also want to check out [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98), or use the search engine of this site to find similar questions that were already answered.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Help us help you. Where, exactly, are you having difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

(a) Suppose that we run k phases of Algorithm 1, using the output G0 produced by one phase as the input G to the next phase and accumulating edges in T. Argue that the overall running time of the k phases is O(kE).
Anwser-

Complexity of above algorithm is O(E). 
There are k number of phases to run.

For each phase, the output of previous phase is input to the next. So, for finding minimum cost edge incident to every vertex (after/before compression of graph), we required to traverse each and every edge.

For each phase time complexity, will be O(E).

Therefore, total time complexity = O(kE)

(b) Suppose that after running k phases of Algorithm 1, as in part (5a), we run Prim's algorithm by calling MST-PRIM (G0; c0; r), where G0, with weight attribute c0, is returned by the last phase and r is any vertex in G0(V). Show how to pick k so that the overall running time is O(E lg lg V ). Argue that your choice of k minimizes the overall asymptotic running time.

Answer -
We have time complexity of above Algorithm 1 for running k phases is, O(kE).

Prim’s algorithm complexity is, O(E logV)

But, here the input of Prim’s algorithms if output of k phases of Algorithm 1.

So, for finding minimum edge weight we require log(logV) time.
This is because the compression of the graph and we just have to find the minimum edge between given two components (or we can say nodes).

(c) For what values of |E| (in terms of |V |) does the above scheme asymptotically beat Prim's algorithm without preprocessing?

For |E| >= |V|

Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question!  So you know, for the future: We prefer that you write an answer only if you are confident in your answer (we don't want you to write an answer if you're not sure about your answer and your only goal is to seek feedback on your answer).  I realize that might not apply in this case.  I'm just sharing this information since I noticed the last sentence in your answer.  Ignore this comment if it doesn't apply to your situation.